# React firebase login with basic if statement gives parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to show a message like "please login" if a user access one of my pages without authorization. I am using `useEffect` and at my render section I wrote a code like below but it gives me parsing error.

**Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?**

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code below:

```
return ( 
    <div className="screens">
        {user ?  (
        <canvas
            ref={ref2}
            className="buildings" 
            width={800}
            height={100}
            onClick={e => {

            }}
        />
        <canvas
            ref={ref}
            className="gameScreen" 
            width={800}
            height={600}
            onClick={e => {

            }}
        />
        <canvas
            ref={ref_yazi}
            className="yazi" 
            width={800}
            height={100}
        />
        ) : (<div>Please login</div>)}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX inside conditions also have to be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Simply wrap your multiple `canvas` elements into a `Fragment` (as the error suggests) or into a div.

```
{user ? ( 
   <> // or <React.Fragment> or a <div>
        <canvas
            ref={ref2}
            className="buildings" 
            width={800}
            height={100}
            onClick={e => {

            }}
        />
        <canvas
            ref={ref}
            className="gameScreen" 
            width={800}
            height={600}
            onClick={e => {

            }}
        />
        <canvas
            ref={ref_yazi}
            className="yazi" 
            width={800}
            height={100}
        /> 
   </>
)
```